# XChacha20poly1305 vulnerability to known plaintext attacks

Tags: passwords, known-plaintext-attack, salsa20

During a security audit, the guy said our cryptosystem is vulnerable to known-plaintext attacks. He said that's because «the implementation uses a crypto_stream_xor() approach» (from libsodium). That's way above my skill, and I did not find anything relevant so far so I'm trying to understand if that's really a problem.

Here is what we do: we derive a key using a global (password, salt) pair. This key −always the same− is used in order to cipher all the documents using xchacha20poly1305. We initialize the stream using `xchacha20poly1305::Stream::init_push`: it provides us with a header (the nonce ?) that we store with the file for decryption later on. We use rust's implementation of libsodium, sodiumoxide.

- Is its assessment correct? (= is xchacha20poly1305 or our usage vulnerable to KPA, and is it due to the fact it uses a xor ?) Didn't the guy mistakingly mixed things with the fact that we reuse password?
- How bad is it? Does it mean that someone who can cipher a known document in our system can decipher anything else it puts its hands on?

**Edit:**
As requested, here is what we do, with more details, using pseudo rust code. I edited out all the irrelevant details but hopefully left enough relevant information and comments.

`password`, `salt`, `chunk_size` are stored in environment variables and never change.

````
function encrypt(file, password, salt, chunk_size) {
    // first, we derive a key
    sodiumoxide::crypto::pwhash::derive_key(
        &mut key,
        &password,
        &salt,
        pwhash::OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
        pwhash::MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
    )

    // Then we initialize the encryption stream
    let (stream, encryption_header) =
        xchacha20poly1305::Stream::init_push(&key);

    // we store the IV
    let encryption_header_bytes = Bytes::from(encryption_header.as_ref());
    store encryption_header_bytes in the output file

    // then we encrypt the file
    buffer = read file content
    while (there are data in the file) {
        // cipher the buffer using xchacha20poly1305's stream
        let encoded = stream.push(&buffer[0..chunk_size], None, Tag::Message).unwrap();
        buffer.advance(chunk_size);
        store `encoded` in the output file
    }
}

function decrypt(encrypted_file, password, salt, chunk_size) {
    // first, we derive a key
    sodiumoxide::crypto::pwhash::derive_key(
        &mut key,
        &password,
        &salt,
        pwhash::OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
        pwhash::MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE,
    )
    // then we read the file in a buffer
    buffer = read encrypted_file content

    // then we read the header, and create a stream out of the header and the key
    let header = Header::from_slice(&buffer[0..xchacha20poly1305::HEADERBYTES])
                        .unwrap();
    stream_decoder = Some(xchacha20poly1305::Stream::init_pull(&header, &key).unwrap());
    buffer.advance(xchacha20poly1305::HEADERBYTES);

    // then we decrypt the rest of the file using said stream
    while(there are data to decrypt in the buffer) {
        let (decrypted, _) = stream
                        .pull(
                            &buffer[0..(xchacha20poly1305::ABYTES + chunk_size)],
                            None,
                        )
                        .unwrap();
        buffer
            .advance(xchacha20poly1305::ABYTES + chunk_size);

        store `decrypted` in the output file
    }
}
```
````

Comment: It might be helpful if you spelled out in a little more detail exactly what your protocol is, and what API you're using.

Comment: That's right. I edited my question with a more accurate explanation of our encryption process.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Link to the documentation for `xchacha20poly1305::init_push`.  2. Write down the protocol in enough detail that you can write a compatible implementation in another language—and _use_ that compatible implementation to generate deterministic known-answer test vectors, and then write automatic tests against those test vectors in your main implementation.

Comment: It's a wrapper around [crypto_secretstream_xchacha20poly1305_init_push](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/927dfe8e2eaa86160d3ba12a7e3258fbc322909c/src/libsodium/crypto_secretstream/xchacha20poly1305/secretstream_xchacha20poly1305.c#L42-L65). The call to [hchacha20](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/927dfe8e2eaa86160d3ba12a7e3258fbc322909c/src/libsodium/crypto_core/hchacha20/core_hchacha20.c#L17) initializes chacha20 with the random IV it generates.

Comment: If it automagically generates the nonce for you, then maybe that's OK (although it doesn't give you the opportunity to immediately reject replay attacks or buggy implementations the way you could if it were a sequence number).  I maintain my recommendation that you write a compatible implementation in another language (preferably with XChaCha and Poly1305 directly rather than via the libsodium composition so that you're confident you understand the protocol and could write it down in the living design document you're maintaining, right?) to generate deterministic known-answer test vectors.

Comment: Ok, I understand better how I can take advantage of using a custom nonce! I can extract this part in order to have the test vectors, those would be super useful.
However I'm sorry but I disagree, writing my own implementation sounds like a terrible idea. It's a well-known fact that nobody should roll its own crypto, making a correct implementation is a job in itself and many failed. libsodium is the state of the art implementation derived from the original work in NaCl of DJB, the guy who originally published Chacha20 and Poly1305, I'd rather keep using proven work.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you write and _deploy_ your own custom implementation of the cryptography, or even that you write a custom implementation of the primitives.  I'm suggesting that you write a custom implementation of the crypto_secretstream API and then _use it to confirm that you understood the protocol_: use it to generate deterministic known-answer test vectors, and then confirm that the code you _really do deploy_ matches what you thought you were computing.

Comment: Oh! I got the nuance now, and that sounds indeed like a great idea!

Comment: Just one thing: the last block should have the `Tag::Final` tag, so that you can later verify that the content wasn't truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Using [crypto_secretstream](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-doc/blob/master/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream.md) that should be fine. It generates a random nonce for each message. Reusing a key in that context is fine.

Original answer, before edit follows:

Yes, that's bad. You have to use a unique IV/nonce for each document.

A stream cipher, such as ChaCha, which is combined with the plaintext using XOR reveals the keystream to anyone who knows the plaintext. That allows them to decrypt other documents. And even if they do not know the plaintext, there can be attacks.

Every document has to have some unique identifier that you can use as a nonce. It does not have to be secret or unpredictable.

Comment: Not just every _document_, but every _version_ of every document too.  For example, if you're encrypting a database field with this and you hash the table name and column name and rowid into a 192-bit nonce, that's _still_ not enough if you ever update the database field with a different value.

Comment: Isn't that taken care of by `xchacha20poly1305::Stream::init_push`? I thought it was in charge of generating the necessary random nonce (that we store in the header of the file for decryption).

Comment: I also edited my question with a better vocabulary: the key is derived from the (password, salt) pair, not (password, IV).

Comment: That depends on the semantics of the operation you're talking about, which is not itself part of libsodium and which I'm not familiar with.  With crypto_secretbox_xchacha20poly1305, it is your responsibility to assign to each message a unique message number.  Maybe the wrapper you're using automatically generates a 192-bit nonce uniformly at random and passes it along with the message, and that's a reasonable thing to do in some cases—but it's better if you can choose message numbers sequentially, like TLS does with the record number, so you can detect replay attacks and buggy implementations.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention crypto_secretstream. If you are using that, then it generates the nonce for you: https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-doc/blob/master/secret-key_cryptography/secretstream.md

Comment: Ok! I'm just a bit surprised to see that using the same key everywhere is OK, so my understanding is that the IV solves that issue.